# Laravel 4.1 gives error Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class FatalErrorException

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php

I have setup a basic REST API on my localhost. I have a little bit of a screwed up configuration. I am using MAMP with PHP 5.5.3 and installed Laravel via

> composer create-project laravel/laravel heartbet --prefer-dist

I have everything working peachy on my localhost and it all seems in order with autoload. However when colleagues are pulling my GIT repo with the laravel CMS in it, it seems that the autload goes bad and it can't find the classes anymore. I am getting the following error on their machines:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class FatalErrorException does not exist' in /Users/claes/co/heartbet/public/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php:316\nStack trace:\n#0 /Users/claes/co/heartbet/public/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php(316): ReflectionParameter->getClass()\n#1 /Users/claes/co/heartbet/public/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php(300): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->hints(Object(ReflectionFunction), Object(ReflectionException))\n#2 /Users/claes/co/heartbet/public/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php(237): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handlesException(Object(Closure), Object(ReflectionException))\n#3 /Users/claes/co/heartbet/public/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php(145): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->callCustomHandlers(Object(ReflectionException))\n#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleException(Object(Reflecti in /Users/claes/co/heartbet/public/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php on line 316

I checked all my autloader and composer and everything seems to be in order. I tried

- composer dump-autoload
- composer install --no-scripts

Also tried something like composer dump-autoload -o without any success. I am still pretty new to the autloading scene and laravel.

Does anybody have any tips on how i can resolve this issue? I find it hard to know where to look for the problem exactly and other answers that i read up on so far all seem to suggest the above two to resolve any directory errors.

Thanks and cheers!
Kenneth

Comment: Check the `/vendor` folder on your colleague's machines and make sure there is stuff in there.  That folder is in the .gitignore file so it's possibly those were never pushed.